# Magento 2: How to add class for custom tab in form ui component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, ui-form

I tried additional classes but it working with the content of my custom tab still not working with my custom tab. So who can help me how to add a class for custom tab?

[image]

**code :-**

```
<fieldset name="custom_tab"> 
     <settings> 
           <label translate="true">Settings</label> 
           <imports> 
                <link name="visible">${ $.provider }:data.hide-export</link> 
           </imports> 
     </settings>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Please apply following code

```
<fieldset name="custom_tab"> 
 <settings> 
       <label translate="true">Settings</label> 
         <additionalClasses>
            <class name="custom_class_name">true</class>
         </additionalClasses>
       <imports> 
            <link name="visible">${ $.provider }:data.hide-export</link> 
       </imports> 
 </settings>
```

Comment: I tried this code but it not working with custom tab

Comment: after this truncate 'ui_component' table and run commands upgrade,deploy,indexer and cache

Comment: It just add class for content of custom tab but i want add class for tab to hide it.

Comment: check this link: https://magentodev.in/how-to-additonalclasses-for-tab-in-magento-2-ui-component-form/

Answer (score 1):

I have checked all the way... but seems currently it not show me anyway to add htmlclass in tab.

I have checked

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition/ui_component.xsd

which only allow below attribute to filedset

```
         <xs:attributeGroup name="ui_element_attributes">
                <xs:attribute ref="name" use="optional" />
                <xs:attribute ref="template" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute ref="component" use="optional" />
                <xs:attribute ref="class" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute ref="provider" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute ref="sortOrder" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute ref="displayArea" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute ref="extends" use="optional"/>
            </xs:attributeGroup>
```

so you can make custom js and hide the tab like below:

```
             jQuery("#tab_general").parent('li').hide();
```